# Handing off a piece of work to a thread and waiting for it to accept

Tags: pthreads, mutex

My application works as follows:
the worker-threads initialize and begin waiting in pthread_cond_wait()
the main thread connects to DB and starts handing over one row at a time to the proper worker

Because of the DB-driver internals, the next row can not be read until the current one is extracted, so the main thread has to wait for the worker to "accept" the row.

I achieve this by calling pthread_cond_wait() inside the main thread -- waiting for a pthread_signal() from the worker. This works cleanly -- on both Linux and FreeBSD -- but *usually* takes much longer on Linux. Whereas I consistently process the entire 1.6M rows in about 27 seconds on FreeBSD, on Linux it usually takes over 2 minutes. Except *sometimes* the Linux box shows the same time...

The code is compiled from the same source and the program talks to the same DB-server. If anything, the Linux box is located on the same LAN as the DB, whereas the FreeBSD machine connects via VPN (so it should be a bit slower). But it is the wide inconsistency of the Linux results that bothers me, and I suspect the thread-coordination...

Here is what I have now:

```
MAIN THREAD                               WORKER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
get new row
figure out, which worker it belongs to    lock my mutex
lock the worker's mutex                   go into pthread_cond_wait
signal the worker                         extract the row's data
unlock the worker's mutex                 signal the main thread
go into pthread_cond_wait                 unlock the mutex
go on back to getting the next row        go on to process the row's data
```

Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If reading the next row must be serial anyway, why are you delegating this to the worker? As the main thread has to wait anyway, have the main thread do the extraction and have the hand-off occur as soon as the row has been sufficiently extracted that the master can proceed to the next row.

Other than that, you will need to provide code, as your description is incomplete, as would be any question of this nature submitted without code.

Comment: I delegate row-processing to the worker, because it is easier to pass one pointer (the row), than several (individual fields). It would not help to do the processing in the main thread, because if the next row is determined to belong to the same thread, the main will have to wait anyway...

Comment: It really isn't harder to pass one pointer than several. That is what struct's are for. I didn't say do the processing in the main thread, I said do the extraction in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you are calling `pthread_cond_wait()` without the mutex locked in the main thread.  This means that there's a race-condition: if the worker thread wakes up, extracts the data and signals the condition *before* the parent executes `pthread_cond_wait()`, the wakeup will be lost.

What you should have is some shared state paired with the condition variable, like this:

**Main Thread:**

```
get_new_row();
worker = decide_worker();

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

/* Signal worker that data is available */
flag[worker] = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

/* Wait for worker to extract it */
while (flag[worker] == 1)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex):

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

**Worker Thread:**

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

/* Wait for data to be available */
while (flag[worker] == 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex):

extract_row_data();

/* Signal main thread that extraction is complete */
flag[worker] = 0;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think, I have the call in the actual code, though -- because I do not get the main thread hanging forever. But I'm wondering, if such use of cond_wait and cond_signal twice (once in each direction) is really necessary for such a common (?) use-case...

Comment: @MikhailT.: It's necessary because you want the worker to wait for something, then you want the main thread to wait for something.  What you're trying to do isn't common - usually, what would happen is that only one thread needs to wait for the other.  Requiring this kind of two-way wait is often a sign that you're doing something in the wrong thread - in this case, you should likely be doing the "extract" part in the main thread, so that the main thread can just hand off the results to the worker and not worry about waiting for it.

Comment: Even if the main thread is doing the extraction, it still has to wait for the worker thread to have accepted the previous assignment. I changed the code as you and Recurse suggested, but it did not make a difference.
What DID make a huge difference was replacing the second pthread_cond_wait with a tight loop:

while (worker_busy)
    pthread_yield();

I don't understand, why this makes such a difference on Linux (2+ minutes vs. 25 seconds of total runtime) -- on FreeBSD both methods are about the same (though using cond_wait consumes less CPU).

Comment: @MikhailT.: For maximum parallelism you want a queue that the main thread can place the extracted work items in and the worker thread(s) can take them from, so that you don't need excessive synchronisation.  It does sound like your program might be triggering some kind of bad scheduler behaviour - maybe the `perf sched` tool can help.

Comment: Yes, I thought about queuing, but, unless I allow the queue to grow without a limit, I'll still need the same two-way synchronization between threads. Changing the scheduling policy is, apparently, not allowed to non-root programs (even for threads of the same process). I tried lowering the priority of the main thread, but without an obvious win. It seems, MySQL is not happy with pthread_mutex-es either -- there is an option for MY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX :-(